# Detect wifi network and get ssid

Tags: c#, maui

How can I get the ssid of detected Wifi networks in a NET MAUI app?

I tried the following method but it's outdated.

```
(WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

var wifiScanResults = wifiManager.ScanResults;
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+api+list+wifi+networks+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.