# How to continue scanning WiFi networks in the background on Android

Tags: android, maui

Hi everyone I'm a new NET MAUI developer. The app I'm creating aims to scan nearby wifi networks, and if it detects a network with a certain ssid it has to execute some instructions. My problem is that I want the app to continue working and therefore scanning wifi networks, even when it is closed. I tried to create a FOREGROUND SERVICE, so that a notification appears that the app is active, and continues to scan the networks. Unfortunately this method only works when the app is active, when the app is closed the scanning stops, but the service continues to work. How can I solve it? How can I continue to scan networks even when the app is closed?

```js
    [Service(ForegroundServiceType = Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeDataSync)]
    public class DemoServices : Service, IServicesTest
    {
        private bool isScanning = false;
        private WifiManager wifiManager;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
              
        }
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("il servizio è iniziato");

                Task.Delay(2000);


                if (!isScanning)
                {
                    isScanning = true;


                    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                    
                    
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {

                            await ScanWifiNetworks();
                           
                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                        }
                    }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                    RegisterNotification();
                }
            }
            else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("il servizio è fermato");
                StopForeground(true);
                StopSelfResult(startId);
            }
            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }

        public async Task ScanWifiNetworks()
        {
            isScanning = true;
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            while (isScanning)
            {
                if (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {

                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.Android)
                        throw new NotSupportedException("Questa funzionalità è supportata solo su dispositivi Android.");

                    var scanResults = new List<ScanResult>();
                    //ottengo il riferimento al servizio WifiManager
                    var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

                    if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
                    {
               
                        wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(true);
                        await Task.Delay(2000);
                    }

                    var wifiScanReceiver = new WifiScanReceiver(wifiManager);
                    Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));

                   
#pragma warning disable CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma
                    wifiManager.StartScan();
#pragma warning restore CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma

                    await Task.Delay(5000); 

                    scanResults.AddRange(wifiScanReceiver.ScanResults);
                    Android.App.Application.Context.UnregisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver);

                    var database = new Database();

                    bool found = false;
                    foreach (var network in scanResults)
                    {
#pragma warning disable CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma
                        if (network.Ssid == "AndroidWifi")
                        {
                            
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
#pragma warning restore CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma
                    }
                    if (found)
                    {
                        MessItem nuovoGeoItem = new MessItem
                        {
                            Data = DateTime.Now,
                            Descrizione = "Entrato"
                        };
                        int esito = await database.AggiungiGeoItem(nuovoGeoItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessItem nuovoGeoItem = new MessItem
                        {
                            Data = DateTime.Now,
                            
                            Descrizione = "Uscito"
                        };
                        int esito = await database.AggiungiGeoItem(nuovoGeoItem);
                    }

                    
                }
            }
        }

        class WifiScanReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            private readonly WifiManager wifiManager;

            public IList<ScanResult> ScanResults { get; private set; }

            public WifiScanReceiver(WifiManager wifiManager)
            {
                this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
                ScanResults = new List<ScanResult>();
            }

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.Action == WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction)
                {
                    // Ricevi i risultati della scansione WiFi
                    var results = wifiManager.ScanResults;
                    ScanResults.Clear();

                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        // Salva l'oggetto ScanResult nella lista
                        ScanResults.Add(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    

        public void Start()
        {
              //  wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(false)   

            Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(DemoServices));
            startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
            MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            
            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, this.Class);
            stopIntent.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
            MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(stopIntent);

        }

       public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            base.OnDestroy();
            //wifiManager = null;
        }




        private void RegisterNotification()
        {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServicioChannel", "Demo de servicio", NotificationImportance.Max);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServicioChannel")
                .SetContentTitle("Servizo Attivo")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();

            StartForeground(100, notification);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `when the app is closed the scanning stops, but the service continues to work.`   I find that you have put the `await ScanWifiNetworks();` into the Service.   Are you saying that the service did not stop, but the function of scanning wifi stopped?

Comment: Yes exactly !!!

Comment: Is there any log? On what Android device were you testing on and what version was it?

Comment: no . I ran the test on the Visual Studio Android emulator, Pixel 5 with Android 13

Comment: Have you checked the [Restrictions after Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan).

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097098/creation-of-foreground-service-on-net-maui-to-scan-wifi-networks Also duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77014396/how-to-make-a-net-maui-app-run-in-the-background Also duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76654370/detect-wifi-network-and-get-ssid You keep spamming the same question over and over.

Comment: so this is not possible due to Android restrictions?

Comment: @louryPe yes, and if you lost your memory from the last time you posted the same question, it is written in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77102768/6643940

Comment: And if I wanted to scan every 30 minutes, how could I do it? Would the method I wrote in the question work? @H.A.H.

Comment: @louryPe I would start by disabling the throttling. So I can be sure that the setting is not stopping me. And then I would test it.

Comment: HI! I tried disabling scan limits via developer options but I have the same problem as above. Do you have any other suggestions? @H.A.H.

Comment: @louryPe your Broadcast receiver, setup this way will not fire. More specifically - it will fire, only if there is main activity running. So if you close the app, the service will run, but you wont receive a thing. And when you start the activity again, it will start firing again.

Comment: thank you so much for your advice!! @H.A.H. How can I keep the Broadcast active?

Comment: @louryPe read my answer, comment on it, when you implement what I said there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of possible issues:

1. Make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />` in your manifest.

If your scans are working in foreground, most likely you did not follow the docs I sent you in my last answer, and you forgot to add it.

If you do not have this permission `StartScan` will plain and simple return 0 results.

2. Just adding this in the manifest, is not enough. You have to ask for this permission. But since this is another place where you can mess up, go to App > Find your application > Permissions > Location, and select "ALLOW ALL THE TIME". (or something like that)

As improvement I say this:
I have not used StartScan with broadcast receiver. I like the solution with ScanResultCallback. It notifies you when your scan result is available.

Looks something like:

```
public class MyScanResultsCallback : ScanResultsCallback
{
    public override void OnScanResultsAvailable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ResultsAvailable");
    }
}
```

Do 1 and 2, and we will talk about how to replace this receiver with lock + callback.